# How to return value of dynamic download links?

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to extract a download link of a tube site, which might be using the server side method described like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724584/how-to-create-dynamic-download-link-in-php) SO question.

The link has no href value and it is bind with a call-back function. So the download link is generated only by clicking.

Manually the link can be extracted by downloading the file, go to the download list of the browser and checking the source url but I want to automate it using Selenium.

Clicking it and calling *current_url* only returns the page url and not the download source.

Is there any way for extracting dynamic links like these with Selenium?